# Shortening Run Statement for C++

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, g++

I recently started using C++ with Microsoft VSCode for competitive programming. Whenever I run the program I have to type

```
g++ filename.cpp -o filename
```

then I would type `filename` in terminal to run the `.exe` file.

In the context of competitive programming, it can be really time consuming to retype this command. Is there a way to shorten this command?

Also, when I make a change to the program is there a better way of recompiling it instead of making another `.exe` file?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What forces you to use `filename` as a name?  Just call your cpp file `x.cpp` or something like that.  And is "competitive programming" a speed-typing exercise?

Comment: Modify [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) to use `g++`

Comment: You could write this command in a script, say  `a.bat`, then just run that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `filename` was just a placeholder and competitive programming is a _very_ popular type of programming where people compete to solve challenging programming questions under a time limit.

Comment: I know what "competitive programming" is.  We get loads of questions that consists of obfuscated, hard-to-read, bad code that is supposedly from "competitive programming".  More often than not, those questions get downvoted due to the poor quality of the question (and the code).

Answer (score 1):

If you are so obsessed with typing `filename` you can always use the `run` button in IDE, or just use `g++ filename.cpp` and it will create `a.out` file. If you need more, then one version of program, then it is much better to save different cpp files, instead of binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Use coderunner addon for VSCode
In config file, add:

```js
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "c": "cd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash && gcc $fileName -o build/$fileNameWithoutExt &&  $dirWithoutTrailingSlash/$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "cpp": "cd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash && g++ $fileName -o build/$fileNameWithoutExt &&  $dirWithoutTrailingSlash/$fileNameWithoutExt"
},    
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

Click right mouse and run code